# Git Stop Tracking Changes but still blind commit

Tags: git, deployment, build, ignore

I would like to put my `/public` (build) dir  in a special state, that is to stop tracking it, and just blind commit it each time I do a commit.

The build dir is a Laravel FW Public dir containing storage symlink, the index.php, and compiled assets.

The important part is I would like to "never see changes"  of `public` in `git status`, which `browsersync`, `gulp`, and `webpack` are constantly updating, and are in full control of.  I have enough files to keep track of, and I don't want them showing up in `git diff` either.

The other important part is that the latest build always end up in the repo, at some point before pushing, so that during deploy time the production server doesn't need to run the build but instead is ready to serve.

I have always came from the school of ignoring the public dir, but now I'm working in an environment where I need the pub files in the repo so that the prod machine doesn't need the compiling tools on it.

I was thinking of something like remove tracking from the files, but still blind commit them.  Do i need a hook for this, what might that hook look like, or is there something easier maybe such as a git command similar to `--assume-unchanged` but that will still commit them?  Does it seem safe to even do this in the confines of Git?

I was also wondering if maybe one solution would be to in `package.json` scripts I can put a script for production deploy that can be ran in the last commit just before pushing the repo to stage(prod).

What kind of solutions are out there for addressing this in git?   Is this even wise?  Does anybody see any problems doing this in the first place?

Comment: You may want to store the built content in it's own repo

Comment: Not a bad idea, I had considered that, but the nature of the framework is such that you will need the vendors outside of the public as well.  So to remove the lines of public data from my status, I would be inheriting another repo to push and maintain, and complicate their deployment procedure, unless I'm missing something.